# Foursquare app gallery

Tags: gallery, foursquare

I developed an android application ( https://market.android.com/details?id=hr.cloudwalk.vg ) that uses Foursquare API and I submitted my application to Foursquare app gallery. It was several days ago and it still isn't showing in gallery although dedicated app page is accessible on: https://developer.foursquare.com/app/foursquare_venue_guess

Is there some sort of approval process and I just have to wait longer? Will I get any answer whatsoever from foursquare? Is there some support mail or support form to contact them about it?

I guess I could be more patient but it was easier to ask than just wait... :-)

Comment: There's a manual approval process that happens on an arbitrarily random irregular basis. Sit tight!

Comment: Btw, you must change the name of your application, as it violates foursquare's trademarks: https://foursquare.com/legal/trademark

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that but it seems it didn't hurt because it is approved and listed on apps page...

Comment: Thanks for warning. I changed the application name and logo..

Comment: I approved it by mistake and then decided to warn you rather than delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a manual approval process that happens on an arbitrarily random irregular basis. Be sure that your app follows foursquare's Trademark policy https://foursquare.com/legal/trademark and attribution guidelines: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/attribution, otherwise it will be rejected